# One form for two models in django

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

```
Django==3.1.7
django-crispy-forms==1.11.2
```

I 've 2 models: Order and OrderList
Order is a header and OrderList is a tabular section of the related Order

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    print_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(
            verbose_name=_("Number"),
            default=get_todays_free_print_number,
        )
    # ... some other fields 

class OrderList(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
            Order,
            blank=False,
            null=False,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    item = models.ForeignKey(
            Item,
            verbose_name=_("item"),
            blank=True,
            null=True,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
    # ... some other OrderList fields
```

**The question is how to create a form containing both models and provide the ability to add an OrderList positions within an Order into the form
and save them both.**

What I did:
forms.py - I used inline formset factory for the OrderList

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit
from .models import Order, OrderList

class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            '__all__',
        ]

class OrderListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderList
        fields = [
            '__all__',
        ]

class OrderListFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    """Use class to display the formset as a table"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.template = 'bootstrap4/table_inline_formset.html'
        
        # I am not sure we should add a button here
        ####################################################
        self.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit',
                               css_class='btn btn-primary offset4'))
```

views.py

```py
@login_required
def orders(request):

    template = f'{APP_NAME}/index.html'

    list_helper = OrderListFormSetHelper()

    list_formset = inlineformset_factory(Order,
                                         OrderList,
                                         OrderListForm,)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = OrderForm(request.POST, prefix="header")

        if form.is_valid() and list_formset.is_valid():
            order = form.save()

            order_list = list_formset.save(commit=False)
            order_list.order = order
            order_list.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('order_created'))

    else:  # all other methods means we should create a blank form
        form = OrderForm()

    
    return render(request, template, {'form': form,
                                      'list_form': list_formset,
                                      'list_helper': list_helper})
```

index.html

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form  %}
    {% crispy list_form list_helper %}

    <!-- the button below doesn't make sense because it does nothing.
          the self.add_input in forms.py already adds a submit button.
               -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {% translate "Send an order" %}
    </button>

</form>
```

The resulting html renders the page like that:
[image: page before submit]

But when I press the submit button
it clean up Order related fields and mark them as blank
[image]

Comment: you want to add the orderlist under order in the forms.py??

Comment: @raven404 yes I do

Comment: can you share your model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `crispy` template tag to render your forms. It uses the `FormHelper` class to help render your forms, which by default has the attribute `form_tag` set to `True` which makes it render a `form` tag for you. Meaning you are **nesting** form tags which does not work and is not possible with the HTML5 standard. You need to set this attribute to `False` to prevent this:

```py
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            '__all__',
        ]
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self) # Explicitly set helper to prevent automatic creation
        self.helper.form_tag = False # Don't render form tag
        self.helper.disable_csrf = True # Don't render CSRF token
```

Next in the helper you make in the view you also have to set these attributes. Furthermore what you call as `list_formset` is not an `instance` of a formset but a **class**, hence you actually need to instantiate the formset class and use it:

```py
@login_required
def orders(request):

    template = f'{APP_NAME}/index.html'

    list_helper = OrderListFormSetHelper()
    list_helper.form_tag = False # Don't render form tag
    list_helper.disable_csrf = True # Don't render CSRF token

    OrderListFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Order,
                                         OrderList,
                                         OrderListForm,)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = OrderForm(request.POST, prefix="header")
        list_formset = OrderListFormSet(request.POST, instance=form.instance) # Instantiate formset

        if form.is_valid() and list_formset.is_valid():
            order = form.save()

            order_list = list_formset.save()
            # Remove below two line, have already instantiated formset with `form.instance` and called save without `commit=False`
            # order_list.order = order
            # order_list.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('order_created'))

    else:  # all other methods means we should create a blank form
        form = OrderForm()
        list_formset = OrderListFormSet(instance=form.instance) # Instantiate formset

    
    return render(request, template, {'form': form,
                                      'list_form': list_formset,
                                      'list_helper': list_helper})
```